# Booting Very slow Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, user-space

Kidnly help me to resolve the booting issue . Previous OS used to boot below 1 Mins . But now its taking more than 3-4 Mins

HDD i5 8th Gen with NVMe Storage

root@benn:~# systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 20.562s (firmware) + 14.037s (loader) + 3.688s (kernel) + 2min 2.656s (userspace) = 2min 40.945s
graphical.target reached after 2min 2.543s in userspace

root@benn:~# systemd-analyze blame | grep -i play
root@benn:~# systemd-analyze blame | grep -i ply
152ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
24ms plymouth-start.service
11ms plymouth-read-write.service
root@benn:~# ^C
root@benn:~# systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 20.562s (firmware) + 14.037s (loader) + 3.688s (kernel) + 2min 2.656s (userspace) = 2min 40.945s
graphical.target reached after 2min 2.543s in userspace
root@benn:~# systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 2.543s
└─multi-user.target @2min 2.542s
└─xrdp.service @2min 1.519s +1.022s
└─xrdp-sesman.service @2min 1.461s +56ms
└─network.target @2min 1.453s
└─networking.service @1.141s +2min 311ms
└─apparmor.service @1.076s +62ms
└─local-fs.target @1.075s
└─run-user-1001-gvfs.mount @2min 2.555s
└─run-user-1001.mount @2min 2.386s
└─swap.target @399ms
└─swapfile.swap @220ms +178ms
└─systemd-remount-fs.service @214ms +5ms
└─systemd-journald.socket @204ms
└─system.slice @204ms
└─-.slice @203ms

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps you, but in my case there were some system (systemd) startup scripts that wouldn't finish until their timeout (Usually 90 seconds).

Find more at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186162/how-to-change-timeout-in-systemctl and the link there.

I also experienced the same with shutdown.

Often, the things those scripts wanted to do were already done after some seconds, but the script wasn't informed about it, so it sits there and waits for its timeout...

Comment: root@benn:/# systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 16.179s (firmware) + 10.407s (loader) + 4.012s (kernel) + 5min 12.400s (userspace) = 5min 43.001s
graphical.target reached after 5min 12.291s in userspace